# Error when trying to get tidy summaries with broomstick for multiple randomForest models

Tags: random-forest, broom

I'm grouping my data frame and fitting each group's data with a random forest model, and then using broomstick to get tidy outputs for each group's model. I'm running into trouble when I get to tidy and augment.

I can group the data and fit the models.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broomstick)
library(randomForest)


data<-data.frame(y=rep(rep(c(1,0),each=100),5),
                 group=rep(c("A","B","C","D","E"), each=200),
                 x1=rnorm(2000),
                 x2=rnorm(2000),
                 x3=rnorm(2000),
                 x4=rnorm(2000),
                 x5=rnorm(2000))

GroupModels<-data%>%
  nest(data= -group)%>%
  mutate(fit = map(data, ~ randomForest(y ~ ., ntree=101, mtry=2, data = .x, importance=TRUE)))
```

I then map glance to the fitted models and that works. I get mse and rsq for each group.

```
GroupModels%>%
  mutate(glanced = map(fit, glance))%>%
  unnest(glanced)%>%
  select(-data, -fit)%>%
  as.data.frame()
```

If I map tidy to the fitted models I get an output and a deprecation warning and I don't understand where tibble::as_tibble() should come into play.

```
GroupModels%>%
  mutate(tidied = map(fit, tidy))%>%
  unnest(tidied)%>%
  select(-data, -fit)%>%
  as.data.frame()
```

> 1: Problem with `mutate()` column `tidied`. i `tidied = map(fit, tidy)`. i This function is deprecated as of broom 0.7.0 and will be
> removed from a future release. Please see tibble::as_tibble().

If I map augment to the models I get an error and I'm not sure what to do with that.

```
GroupModels%>%
  mutate(augmented = map(fit, augment))%>%
  unnest(augmented)%>%
  select(-data, -fit)%>%
  as.data.frame()
```

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `augmented`. i `augmented = map(fit, augment)`. x argument must be coercible to non-negative
> integer

Answer (score 0):

I can now get augment to work using "map2", didn't know about this, but it's handy when you need both the fit and the data for a function. I guess I'll worry about the deprecation warning when it happens.

```
GroupModels%>%
  mutate(augmented = map2(fit, data, augment))%>%
  unnest(augmented)%>%
  select(-data, -fit)%>%
  as.data.frame()
```